# How can I check whether an object is locked using JPA2?

Tags: java, locking, jpa-2.0

How can I check whether an object is locked using JPA2?

If I'm correct `entityManager.getLockMode()` checks whether **I** have a lock, not whether someone else has a lock on the object.

I can check by trying to get a lock and catching the exception, but then the transaction is automatically rolled back ... and I don't want the overhead of creating more transactions than needed.

Thanks in advance,
Pieter

Comment: What is your use case? You should not have to worry about this.

Comment: I want to show whether something is locked in the UI

Comment: By the time you would display it on the UI, the object would (hopefully) not be locked anymore: transactions should be as short as possible, especially if they use locks. Note that the lock is not a lock on the object, but a lock in database.

Comment: JB Nizet is right. Here's a resource to better understand locking modes: http://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and

Comment: So what solution do you propose? My requirements are: only one user can change the object at a time, the changing of the object is one (long) transaction (all or nothing) and other users should be able to see that the changing is going on.